# Initialization List Problems

Tags: c++

```
DoubleVector::DoubleVector(unsigned int buffer) : len(buffer), data(new base_int[len]), start(len / 2), end(start)
```

This produces a very large values for both start and end even though the buffer is set to 50.  len contains the correct value of 50 but start and end both contain some value over a million.  I then changed to code to the following.

```
DoubleVector::DoubleVector(unsigned int buffer) : len(buffer), data(new base_int[len]), start(buffer / 2), end(start)
```

Now both start and end were initialized with the correct values of 25.  Why?  Are you not supposed to assume there is any order in which the variables will be initialized?

Comment: Crank up your compiler warning level to 11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of base member initialisation is the order that the member variables appear in the class definition.

It's best not to rely on that. (As to do so makes code very brittle).